# update div with a image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel

i am using this plugin: http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/ to do a carousel, but, above have a div where i want update with the clicked image. how i can do it? here a image showing how it will work:

[image: image showing how my carousel is]

```
<div class="main-image">
 <img src="http://mysite.com/image.jpg">
</div>

<div class="carousel">
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><img src="http://mysite.com/image.jpg"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="http://mysite.com/image.jpg"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="http://mysite.com/image.jpg"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="http://mysite.com/image.jpg"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It says how to do it right here http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/?#doc

Comment: @Joren can you be more specific, I see nowhere on that page that talks about setting the image external to the carousel.

Comment: @Joren, i do it. thanks, other solutions posted here work too.

Answer (score 4):

Try putting this into your document ready section

```
// This is untested but it should work
$('.carousel li>a').click(function(){
    $('.main-image').find('img').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
});
```

Comment: there is a ")" missing but I'd still give +1 because it's a nice way of doing it

Answer (score 1):

I checked their documentation and they don't seem to have any option to show the active image in original size on top. You have to write all the javascript codes by yourself to build a module into it,

or simply use [**CoolCarousel Frebsite slider - type 61**](http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/61/) that is identical with your plugin.

Comment: Flexslider also is a very good slider plugin